# my number input should accept only numbers[0-9] and [-] character

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

should accept and [0-9] and [-] character and it should be max and min 12 characters and  **123-456-7890** format

`<input type="number" onchange="regex.test(^[0-9-]*$)">`

**error** : Expression expected

Comment: please help me out if any one knows the answer. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you need one string like  123-456-7890? try this:

```
var t = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g
t.test('123-456-7890')
```

Comment: is this correct writing ?
    var t = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;
    if(parent.eq(0).children().eq(2).val() == t.test(123-456-7890)){
     console.log("stack overflow");
    }

Comment: '123-456-7890' is the value what you want to check.  so: var t = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;val value = parent.eq(0).children().eq(2).val();if(t.test(value)){console.log("stack overflow");}

Comment: **var t** = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;
    **var q** = 123-456-7890
    console.log(q === t.test(123-456-7890)) // **false**

Comment: yeah, var q = '123-456-7890',q is a string,and: var t = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;var p = t.test('123-456-7890')// true,p is boolean.

Comment: it is taking that format. it is fine. if i give **123-456-7890abc** it is accepting

Comment: var t = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;var k = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/g; yeah,t  just check contain.and k check all right.   /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/g   is right.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex -

```js
var regex = /^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
regex.test('123-123-1234');
```

Comment: var t = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;
    var q = 123-456-7890
    console.log(q === t.test(123-456-7890))//false